# Uber integration login error : expired_jwt

Tags: android, authentication, uber-api, uberjar

I want to integrate Uber SDK in my app, I am getting **'expired_jwt'** error.

Following is my code:

```
    configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
            //.setServerToken(SERVER_TOKEN)
            .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
            .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.ALL_TRIPS, Scope.PROFILE))
            .build();

    accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(this);

    //Use a custom button with an onClickListener to call the LoginManager directly
    loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager, new UberLoginCallback(), configuration, LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE);
```

//For login

```
loginManager.login(MainActivity.this);
```

//Then I am getting result in

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    loginManager.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

// UberLoginCallback class is like this:

```
private class UberLoginCallback implements LoginCallback {

    @Override
    public void onLoginCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Error : " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authorizationCode) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authorization Code : " + authorizationCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

In 'onLoginError()' I am getting error 'expired_jwt'

Answer (score 1):

JWT includes the timestamp for the response. We use a 30 second window of validation. The device/emulator you're using probably doesn't have an accurate system time. Please fix the time and try again.